# Graph taxonomy

Tags: graph, naming, convention

Knowing an edge is defined by both **initial** and **final** vertices,
How do you call edges coming **from** and **to** a vertex ?
For now, I name those **incoming** and **outgoing**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In-edge and out-edge.